# Testcafe - How do you wait for the `before` hook to complete before loading the page

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using the `test.before` hook. My understanding is that this would be completed before the test would load the page.

What I am required to do is a `navigateTo` as the first action in my test.

`test.page("/home").before(async t => {
  await setupMockApis()
})("The bank account is added", async t => {
  // the mock APIs are not finished setting up
  // so I am required to do a navigateTo first
  t.navigateTo("/home");
});`

Is this the expected behaviour? Is it possible to get the before to complete before the test loads the page?

Answer (score 2):

The common scenario is to login in before hook and it is implied that the page is loaded. In your case, you can avoid unnecessary page load omitting the `page` function call and navigating to your page in the hook as follows:

```
test.before(async t => {
  await setupMockApis();
  await t.navigateTo("/home");
})("The bank account is added", async t => {
});
```